# Decomposition of Radon measures

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Let $\mathscr{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the vector space of all Radon measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\mathscr{H}^d$ denote the Hasudorff $d$-dimensional measure for $d\leq n$. If $S\subset \Omega$ is such that $\mathscr{H}^d(S)<\infty$ then 
\begin{gather*}
\nu:= \mathscr{H}^d \llcorner S\\
\nu(A)= \mathscr{H}^d(A\cap S) 
\end{gather*} 
defines a Radon measure, i.e. $\nu\in \mathscr{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Similarly given a set $S$ and a $\mathscr{H}^d\llcorner S$ summable function $g$ the formula
\begin{equation}
\gamma(A)=\int_{A\cap S} g \;d\mathscr{H}^d\qquad \nu = g\;\mathscr{H}^d\llcorner S
\end{equation}
defines a Radon measure.

### QUESTION

To me it seems reasonable to consider the set of all measures of the type $\gamma $ defined above as a "base" for all the Radon measures. Consequently is it true that given a Radon measure $\mu\in\mathscr{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ there exists a family of sets $\{S_d\}_{d\in [0,\infty)}$ and a family of functions $\{g_d\}_{d\in [0,\infty)}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\mu=\int_{0}^\infty \;\;g_d\mathscr{H}^d\llcorner S_d \;\;d\mathscr{L}^1(d).
\end{equation*}

The latter is then equivalent, in some sort of way, to: is there a measure $\mu \in \mathscr{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which is singular to all Hausdorff measures?

### UPDATE

I found a work from C.D.Culter "The Hausdorff measure distribution of finite measures in euclidean space", in which this kind of decomposition is treated.
https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v38/cjm1986v38.1459-1484.pdf

Comment: I wonder what happens if you take $\mu$ to be a [biased coin flip measure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250284/measure-induced-on-0-1-by-infinite-tosses-of-biased-coin)?

Comment: Say that you have coin that has probability $.2$ to obtain  H (head) and $.8$ to obtain T (tail). Then you map it into $\mathbb{R}$ via a random variable that maps $H\to -1$ and $T\to1$. The probability measure $\mu$ that you obtain $\mathbb{R}$ can be easily written as \begin{equation*} \mu= .2 \delta_{-1}+.8\delta_{1}.\end{equation*} Therefore setting $S_0=\{-1,1\}$, \begin{equation*}g_0:=\begin{cases}.2 &\mbox{ for } x=-1\\.8 &\mbox{ for } x=1\end{cases}\end{equation*} one easily obtains the decomposition.

Comment: That isn't what I meant; see the link.  Let $X_i$ be iid taking values 0,1 with probabilities $1-p, p$ respectively, and let $\mu$ be the law of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i} X_i$.  For $p=1/2$ you recover 1-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.  For $p \ne 1/2$ you get an atomless measure which is singular to Lebesgue measure, and that's what I'm referring to here.  One might guess that it would also be singular to lower-dimension Hausdorff measures.  But in light of the paper you've cited, maybe not (I haven't read the result carefully yet).

Comment: Well, I have worked a little bit to get into the example. Indeed the situation seems very interesting  here I made a quick code with matlab to helo me visualize the situation:

https://gist.github.com/ferrarilad/a90b8065d5cf8a327c4d1ad28d32b7fe

I have the felling it should converge to some kind of Cantor type function. I will reflect on it to understand if it is actually possible to obtain the exact measure.